# Find an antiderivative of the function

Tags: calculus

Let $u: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Find an antiderivative of $u^2u'''$ in terms of $u$ and its derivatives.

Note: I know an antiderivative of $uu'''$ is $uu''-\frac{u'^2}{2}$. However it seems for this problem one needs to evaualate antiderivative of either $uu'u''$ or $u'^3$ which can't be computed easily via integration by parts

Comment: I'm not sure that a simple expression exists in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the independent variable $t$ and integrating by parts twice with letting the derivable function to be $u^2(t)$ in first integration and $u(t)$ in the second one, we get

> $$  u^2 \left( t \right)  u''\left( t \right) -u \left( t \right)u'{^2} \left( 
> t \right) +\int \!  u'^{3}\left( t \right)  {dt}.$$

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to avoid $\int$, else he could have simply written $\int u^2u'''$.